# Calculate time difference for panel data in mysql

Tags: mysql, time, panel-data

I have a table (called "Sessions") that looks like this:

```
user_id | action | datetime  
1       |  1     |  2015-12-06 20:15:46  
1       |  2     |  2015-12-06 20:15:56  
2       |  1     |  2015-12-06 10:01:36  
2       |  2     |  2015-12-06 10:01:39  
1       |  1     |  2015-12-07 18:17:46  
1       |  2     |  2015-12-07 18:17:56  
2       |  1     |  2015-12-07 14:03:46  
2       |  2     |  2015-12-07 14:03:49
```

I'd like to use mysql to calculate the number of seconds each user spends on each activity ("duration"), which is the difference between datetime for a given user_id on a given day, getting:

```
user_id |  action |  datetime             | duration  
1       |   1     |   2015-12-06 20:15:46 |      10  
1       |   2     |   2015-12-06 20:15:56 |      NaN  
2       |   1     |   2015-12-06 10:01:36 |      3         
2       |   2     |   2015-12-06 10:01:39 |      NaN
```

I can make it work for a series but not the panel. Thank you!

Comment: Is duration calculated from the difference in datetime from action 1 and action 2 for a given user_id?

Comment: Yes. I will modify my question.

Comment: `SELECT session.action, session.datetime, (tableB.datetime - session.datetime) AS duration FROM session INNER JOIN tableB ON tableB.action = (session.action + 1) ORDER BY session.action;`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time and help.

Comment: this won't work because of these "NaN" you expect to get: this means you are crossing one table with nothing on the other side: so a left outer join or a right outer join is needed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution consists in crossing the same table twice, one will correspond to the "first action" that happens and the other will correspond with the "next action". The requisites then can be expressed in the "on" part of the query:

```
select first_action.user_id, 
       first_action.action, 
       first_action.datetime,
       (next_action.datetime - first_action.datetime) duration
  from
  (select * from sessions) as first_action 
  left outer join (select * from sessions) as next_action
  on first_action.user_id = next_action.user_id
  and first_action.action + 1 = next_action.action
  and date(first_action.datetime) = date(next_action.datetime);
```

Comment: well the op does mention 'on a given day'. perhaps that can be worked into the solution

Comment: I've missed this part, thanks for letting me know. I will make an edit in a while correcting this

Comment: Yes, I should have written the question more precisely -  For a given user, on a given day.  And thanks Raul, I think I can work with this. I'll try it now.

Answer (score 1):

E.g. something like...

```
SELECT x.user_id
     , x.action
     , x.datetime start
     , y.datetime stop
     , TIMEDIFF(y.datetime,x.datetime) duration 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.user_id = x.user_id 
   AND DATE(y.datetime) = DATE(x.datetime) 
   AND y.action = 2 
 WHERE x.action = 1 
 ORDER 
    BY user_id
     , start;
```